# Ajax error and weird white space when connected

Tags: ajax

When connected in Drupal (the problem does NOT happen when logged out), I see a strange � character.

The character seem to break Ajax calls all over the admin (I get an alert, with code 200, and the result of the Ajax request). I get the error when editing views, adding some contents, etc. Anything that requires Ajax.

The character also appears on every pages of the website, but only if I'm logged in Drupal. Otherwise, it doesn't appear.

I figured, the problem can't be in a file, or it would happen when I'm logged out too ?

Is there some files that are only called when logged in ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution so I'm going to post in case anyone has a similar problem.

First, I made sure I had no unnecessary PHP closing tag, just like Drupal recommands.
I also checked for the character in the database, just in case.

I started commented the page_top, page and page_bottom of my html.tpl.php to see where the problem was.

Turns out, with nothing in the html.tpl.php, (and I mean NOTHING), I still had the character.

I created a random "test.php" with simply an empty  and still had the problem. A similar "test.html" (HTML is the key here), it worked.

Someone had activated a "mod_deflate" in the .htaccess and it seemed to have issues with my version of PHP.

So there it is, hopefully it can help someone.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Content on your Drupal site varies depending on the role of the user. Authenticated users have different menus and menu structures, different block might be displaying etc.

When Drupal renders the page conditional code outputs different html depending on whether the user is autheticated or not. You have most likely copied something from a word processor over into a theme file and now you are stuck with a character that is nor properly encode by the browser. Look at the surrounding html tags to this character to give you an idea about where it is generated. If it is surrounded by div tags with class of field, check which node this field belongs to, which block or region etc.

And you possibly have misformed html. Right click on your web page and inspect the source. Copy the whole lot and go look online for a HTML verifier to check your code for you, ie. [HTML Validator](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html)